# Why the state position for a Key calculated by this way for the Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am reading the Flink source code for how to calculate the state position in the array for a Key, and found the state position calculated by keyGroupIndex-keyGroupOffset,
my questions are:

1. Why use the keyGroupIndex-keyGroupOffset as the position, why not use the state[keyGroupIndex] directly?

   Also I found state array assigned with the size Number Of KeyGroups by the statement `Map<N, Map<K, S>>[] state = (Map<N, Map<K, S>>[]) new Map[keyContext.getNumberOfKeyGroups()];` , if using `state[keyGroupIndex]` directly , it should also be one to one mapping.
2. Why we need the KeyGroupRange?

Below code extracted from the source code NestedMapsStateTable.java

```java
this.keyGroupOffset = keyContext.getKeyGroupRange().getStartKeyGroup();

@VisibleForTesting
Map<N, Map<K, S>> getMapForKeyGroup(int keyGroupIndex) {
    final int pos = indexToOffset(keyGroupIndex);
    if (pos >= 0 && pos < state.length) {
        return state[pos];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private int indexToOffset(int index) {
    return index - keyGroupOffset;
}

public NestedMapsStateTable(InternalKeyContext<K> keyContext, RegisteredKeyedBackendStateMetaInfo<N, S> metaInfo) {
    super(keyContext, metaInfo);
    this.keyGroupOffset = keyContext.getKeyGroupRange().getStartKeyGroup();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<N, Map<K, S>>[] state = (Map<N, Map<K, S>>[]) new Map[keyContext.getNumberOfKeyGroups()];
    this.state = state;
}
```

https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/63c04a516f40ec2dca4d8edef58e7c2ef563ce67/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/state/heap/NestedMapsStateTable.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that every `StateBackend` is responsible for a sub set of the complete key group range. Therefore, we only have to store a state map for each key group in our range. In order to do the state map management we normalize the key group indices such that they start with `0`.

However, there is a small error in the code which allocates a state map entry for each key group in the complete range. This should be fixed. Here is the corresponding [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-6899).

Comment: Thank you for your help Till.